# SQL Server License identification

Tags: sql-server, licensing

We purchased a SQL server license with 10 user CALS, a while ago. How can I identify the users accessing the SQL server to make sure number of CALS match the number of users accessing the server? Is there some tool to achieve this? or may be some manual process?

Please help.

Regards.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking at a manual process. Microsoft gave up on automated license tracking for everything except Terminal Services years ago. There is enough "nuance" and interpretation in their licenses that no automated system can accurately count their usage. (In addition, I'd argue that they've eschewed automated license compliance mechanisms so that they can be free to "interpret" their licenses in litigation as they see fit. It would be pretty hard to argue that a Customer wasn't in compliance if Microsoft's own tool told the Customer that they were in compliance.)

Comment: Thanks Evan for the reply. Any idea about the manual p[rocess??

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT login_name FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions
```

Comment: Processor licenses? External connector licenses? Device vs user CALs?

Comment: He clearly said "Client Access Licenses". This means concurrent users.

Comment: Device CALs are CALs. User CALs are CALs. Differentiate based on the query above.